# How can I use netplan match on macaddress when I then bond the nic?

Tags: networking, server, netplan, network-bonding

```yaml
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0: # usb ethernet 1
      match:
        macaddress: f8:e4:3b:55:72:71
      set-name: eth0
      dhcp4: no
    eth1: # builtin
      match:
        macaddress: e6:30:ac:f2:31:63
      set-name: eth1
      dhcp4: no
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: no
      interfaces:
        - eth0
        - eth1
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.4/24
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.0.1
        metric: 0
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.4.4.8
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: eth0
        mii-monitor-interval: 1
  version: 2
```

Basically I have 3 ethernet ports I am bonding into one. However, this bond re-assigns the MAC addresses:

```
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:30:ac:f2:31:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:30:ac:f2:31:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

So on boot it's all fine (i.e. it finds the matching NICs and renames them), but then when I run `netplan apply`:

```
WARNING:root:Cannot find unique matching interface for eth1
WARNING:root:Cannot find unique matching interface for eth0
```

I don't think this causes any issues, given the NIC's name has been reassigned already at boot - but it is a bit of an annoying warning to see - and will potentially make it harder to make changes without constant reboots.

Is there a way to use netplan based on the "true" MAC address - and it not give me the warning?

Comment: Note that https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/netplan-yaml/ claims *"...This doesn’t match virtual MAC addresses for veth, bridge, bond, vlan, …"* - this is a confusing sentence to me, but either way the current behaviour seems to be that is *does* match on virtual MAC (and then fails, because of duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

Bonded interfaces necessarily have the same mac address, and therefore it is not possible to uniquely match an interface on mac address once the bond has been created.  There is no concept of a "real" mac address for an interface - once the mac has been updated, this is the only mac address for the interface as known by the kernel, udev, systemd-networkd, and netplan.

In general, renaming network interfaces to the "legacy" naming convention (ethN) is discouraged, though I see that one listed as USB of your interfaces is commented as USB so it's understandable why you would want a cleaner interface name.  You may find it reasonable to match by driver in order to rename the USB interface, and leave the name of the non-USB interface as-is.